# Path calculations

Tags: javascript, math

I've a game with planets and ships. I've succeed to calculate planetaries paths, ships path (easy!), but now i tried to calculate path to meet ship and planet.
I've many variables (angles, speed, etc...) so the result of planet position is :

Ppx is Planet position X, Ppy Planet position Y, Ppz planet position Z.

startX is initial planet position X, [...]

speedPlanetMillis is Speed of planet

angleStartX is angle between star and planet at time 0

```
Ppx = (startX*(Math.cos(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI)) +  startY*Math.sin(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))*(Math.cos(angleStartZ)*Math.cos(angleStartY)) +  (startX*(-1*Math.sin(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))+startY*Math.cos(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))*(Math.sin(angleStartZ)*Math.cos(angleStartX) - Math.cos(angleStartZ)*Math.sin(angleStartY)*Math.sin(angleStartX)) + startZ*(Math.sin(angleStartZ)*Math.sin(angleStartX) + Math.cos(angleStartZ)*Math.sin(angleStartY)*Math.cos(angleStartX));

Ppy = (startX*(Math.cos(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI)) +  startY*Math.sin(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))*(-1*Math.sin(angleStartZ)*Math.cos(angleStartY))+(startX*(-1*Math.sin(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))+startY*Math.cos(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))*(Math.cos(angleStartZ)*Math.cos(angleStartX)+Math.sin(angleStartZ)*Math.sin(angleStartY)*Math.sin(angleStartX))+startZ*(Math.cos(angleStartZ)*Math.sin(angleStartX)+Math.sin(angleStartZ)*Math.sin(angleStartY)*Math.cos(angleStartX));

Ppz = (startX*(Math.cos(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI)) +  startY*Math.sin(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI)) * (-1*Math.sin(angleStartY)) + (startX*(-1*Math.sin(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI))+startY*Math.cos(Decimals(now * speedPlanetMillis) * 2 * Math.PI)) * (-1*Math.cos(angleStartY) * Math.sin(angleStartX)) + startZ * (Math.cos(angleStartY) * Math.cos(angleStartX));
```

Fomulas for ships paths is more easy because it's a right :

Pvx is ship position X, [...]

```
Pvx = now * speedShipMillis * (Math.abs(shipDestinationX - shipStartX) / (Math.abs(shipDestinationX - shipStartX) + Math.abs(shipDestinationY - shipStartY) + Math.abs(shipDestinationZ - shipStartZ))) + shipStartX;

Pvy = now * speedShipMillis * (Math.abs(shipDestinationY - shipStartY) / (Math.abs(shipDestinationX - shipStartX) + Math.abs(shipDestinationY - shipStartY) + Math.abs(shipDestinationZ - shipStartZ))) + shipStartY;

Pvz = now * speedShipMillis * (Math.abs(shipDestinationZ - shipStartZ) / (Math.abs(shipDestinationX - shipStartX) + Math.abs(shipDestinationY - shipStartY) + Math.abs(shipDestinationZ - shipStartZ))) + shipStartZ;
```

So i try to find value of "now" when Pvx = Ppx, Pvy = Ppy and Pvz = Ppz. At this moment, shipDestinationX = Ppx, [...]

I've tried to factor, explode, transform sinus to cosinus... But i've failed to resolve this mathematic system. Can you help me?

Regards.

Comment: I can simplify formula for ship as `ship.x=x0+t*ship.vx` (while velocity component is calculated strangely - with Mathattan metrics). But formula for planets is too long for reading. Could you simplify it like me?

Comment: This formula works if you have the ship speed for each coordinates (x, y, z). But if i says that my ship fly at 10m/s, if i move to +10x, +10y +10z, i will fly at 3.33m/s on X, 3.33m/s on y and 3.33m/s onz. If you move to +30x, +20y, 10+z i will fly at 10/(30/(30+20+10))m/s on X, 10/(20/(30+20+10))m/s on Y and 10/(10/(30+20+10))m/s on Z.

It's why formula is more complex for ship.

For planet the algorithm is :
- I move on XY layout like my planet is on ecliptic
- I do a rotation on XZ/YZ.

So these 2 rotations give this formulas.

Comment: These are easy calculations for anyone who understands vectors in 3D.  How much background do you have?

Comment: @Chklang, either I don't understand you, or you don't understand Vectors. in particular *(normalized)* direction vectors. And as far as I get the algo for the planet, you've rolled out the product of 3 3DMatrix transformations *(a rotation matrix times a scaling matrix consisting of the product of another matrix multiplication)* !? If I get your problem right, you want to calculate when and where these two movements meet / adapt the path of the ship accordingly, I'd not know how to solve this equation anymore. I'd brute-force it by doing a binary search.

Comment: @Thomas, i've applied 3d matrix (found on wikipedia) and i've extracted fomulas to write functions in javascript (for tests) and java (for end product). By these matrix i've getted it. Maybe my calculs are wrong...